# How to traverse between combination of textfields and textviews using next button on the keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextview

If the sequence only contain either textfields or textviews, I can do it. But what about mixed sequence?

Comment: you can use IQKeyboard library for that

Comment: Whats the problem with a mixed sequence?

Answer (score 1):

This is not very complicated. I usually maintain the sequence using an array of views:

```
// put your input fields here
let fields: [UIView] = [self.textField1, self.textView1, self.textField2]

func switchToNext(from field: UIView) {
   guard let index = fields.index(of: field) else {
      return
   }

   if index + 1 == fields.count {
      // handle the last item
      field.resignFirstResponder()
   } else {
      let next = fields[index + 1]
      next.becomeFirstResponder()
   }
}
```

You can call the method from both `UITextFieldDelegate` and `UITextViewDelegate`:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ field: UITextField) {
   switchToNext(from: field)
}
```